# Smart Assembly - What stops a project working?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, smartassembly

We have several ASP.NET applications which reuse many projects. Let's say

Solution/App A contains projects p1, p2, p3
and
Solution/App B contains projects p2, p3, p4

We try obfuscating all projects in both applications and neither work. When we obfuscate p1, p2 in application A then it works. But we can happily obfuscate p3 and p4 in app B and that also works.

So, sometimes we can obfuscate p3 and sometimes we can't. It's a solution level issue, but our question is WHY? What things should be avoided or looked at to get more consistent obfuscation behavior?

Thanks

Edit 1

"What defines the project not working?"
Typically I get some kind of DLL issue, hinting it no longer understands the references properly somewhere (often an external DLL which is being embedded instead of merged and obfuscated). As such, it errors on start up normally.

Comment: Can you elaborate on _stops a project working_? There must be some detailed error description somewhere that can shine some light on your issue.

Comment: Yes, I've added an edit. Thanks

Comment: Your description is not very detailed making it hard to help solve your problem: _DLL issue_ and _it errors_ is not very detailed.

Comment: It's also unfortunately all I've got. Literally, when I obfuscate a project, then suddenly I get DLL reference errors for an external DLL. When I dont obfuscate, it works. Meaning it somehow looses it's reference. If you have any idea what else I could do to get more detail please let me know